# Multiple user editing single Excel file using Single GUI

Tags: excel

could anyone suggest a way multiple user can access single Excel file(Database) using Single userform. I have a system where multiple users have to update single excel file (Adding or deleting record). So could any of you suggest how should i proceed. I know this is an software process question rather than a software code question. But still asking, if Anybody could help me as i cannot find a feasible solution to do so.

Comment: Have you looked into using a database backend?  It is probably the easiest way to accomplish what you want.  Each user of Excel would see what recorders are in the database backend.  Then when a command is issued, the contents of the database are written to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a network share available, would 'Shared Workbook' do the trick? (sounds a lot like it to me). You basically check a box that the workbook is from now on 'shared'. Excel will allow several users in parallel to open the same file *for editing*. It will make sure that everyones writes end up in the file (and that each save gives you others' edits).

You can find more info e.g. here: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/About-the-shared-workbook-feature-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you want, but you an have multiple users editing multiple files, but have the data combined into a single file. This will work as long as you have a fixed maximum number of data editors (say 20). Just create a simple data entry file with the userform built in that stores the data entered in a sheet. Now create 20 copies of this, one for each user, and store them in a file sharing environment like SharePoint or a shared network drive. Now you can have the master "database" file aggregate them into a single file by using workbook links.

In order to be able to do things with them as if they were a single data set, you need to do a sort of union of the data, which is not straightforward in Excel. Again, you need to establish a hard maximum size for each user to edit - for example, 5000 rows. On a Sheet in your database workbook, designate rows 2-5001 for the first user, then leave an empty row (usually I color it black to make it easy to spot), then 5002-10003 for the next user, etc. In Cell B2, put the formula

`=if('J:\Network folder\[Data Entry 1.xlsm]DataSheet'!B2="","",'J:\Network folder\[Data Entry 1.xlsm]DataSheet'!B2)`

and fill that to all the cells in that range (down to row 5001). Then repeat in the next range (B5002, for the second range:

`=if('J:\Network folder\[Data Entry 2.xlsm]DataSheet'!B2="","",'J:\Network folder\[Data Entry 1.xlsm]DataSheet'!B2)`